# MySQL counting question

Tags: php, mysql

How do I find out which user entered the most articles and then count how many articles that user entered using PHP & MySQL.

Here is my MySQL tables.

```
CREATE TABLE users_articles (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
title TEXT NOT NULL,
acontent LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
pass CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select count(*) as coun, user_id  from users_articles group by user_id order by coun desc LIMIT 1`

Comment: "take the top row" == "LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(id) AS articles 
FROM users_articles 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY articles DESC
LIMIT 1;
```